# Update package.json version with pre-commit hook

Tags: node.js, git, package.json, husky

I'm trying to automate the version bump of a Node.js project hosted on a private github repo.

The project is meant to run locally, so it's not published, neither released. People in my organization just pull the `main` branch and run it on their machines with `yarn && yarn start`.

#### What I want to achieve

What I want to achieve is that in the pre-commit phase a version bump is made (major, patch or minor) to the `package.json` of this project and committed together with the code changed according to the commit message.

All I want to do is that my PR is including the change in the `package.json` without me having to do it manually. I don't need releases or CI for this.

#### What I did successfully

I have setup Husky and commitlint in order to validate conventional commit message and it works fine.

#### What I tried, but failed

I tried to use `semantic-release` and other packages to provide this functionality, but they all imply there's a CI build or release somewhere so I'm stuck.

Any idea?

Comment: I assume you would like to upgrade version based on commit message according to convetional commits? For example, feat commit type will upgrade only minor etc.

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk exactly.

Answer (score 3):

in case you have any kind of CICD pipeline (not entirely limited to git hooks scope) you can use [gitversion cli](https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/cli/)

it supports version bump per commit message regex [configuration example](https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/configuration):

```yaml
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
```

means that a commit with message `my commit msg +semver: fix` will trigger a `patch` version bump

see [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/automatic-semantic-versioning-by-using-gitversion-9e22edecb116) with detailed explanation for setup.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `pre-commit` you should use the `commit-msg` hook.
The `pre-commit` hook is triggered before there is a commit message yet, but if you use the `commit-msg` hook, it will be triggered after there is a commit message.
The hook will trigered your script and the first argument your script will receive will be the commit message itself.

Then you can write any logic on top of the commit message. You can check the message, and update version based of the message as you requested.  There are many ways to it

```
npm version major
```

Answer (score -2):

you can user updateCommitId modules to write custom node JS code to run during pre-commit hook. Sample working code can look like below. Please upgrade as deemed required.

```
{
  "version": "1.12.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "pre-commit": ["updateCommitId"],
  "scripts": {
    "updateCommitId": "node updateVersion.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "semver": "^7.3.5",
    "simple-git": "^3.2.6"
  }
}
```

```js
const semver = require("semver");
const simpleGit = require("simple-git");

const options = {
  baseDir: process.cwd(),
  binary: "git",
  maxConcurrentProcesses: 6,
};

const git = simpleGit(options);

const json = require("./package.json");

function savePackage() {
  require("fs").writeFileSync(
    process.cwd() + "/package.json",
    JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)
  );
}
async function updateVersion() {
  try {
    if (json.version) {
      const version = semver.parse(json.version);
      version.inc("minor");
      json.version = version.toString();
      savePackage();
      await git.add("package.json");
      process.exit(0);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

updateVersion();
```